# How to document and window on Chrome Extension v3?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I can't make it work this Chrome extension (at first it worked but now I'm struggling with it and I don't know what I'm doing wrong).

I get this errors:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
> Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined

I tried different ways of adding the load event and calling the window object following the Chrome documentation but is always wrong, so I share my original code below.

Here is my code:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "description": "",
    "author": "",
    "icons": {
        "16": "icon.png",
    },
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "main.js"
    },
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_title": ""
    },
    "permissions": [
      "storage",
      "activeTab",
      "tabs",
      "contextMenus"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "js": ["main.js"],
          "css": ["style.css"],
          "matches": ["https://www.google.com/*"]
        }
      ]
  }
```

**main.js**

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  let currentLocation = window.location.href;

  //Detect if there is a search
  if(currentLocation.includes("q=")) {
  
    //Get saved words
    let badWords = [];

    chrome.storage.sync.get({words:[]}, function(result) {
      if(result.length > 0) {
        badWords = result;
      }
    });
  
    //Avoid searching selected words
    search = currentLocation.split("q=")[1].split("+")[0];
    
    badWords.forEach(word => {
      if(search === word || search.includes(word)) {
        history.back();
      }
    });
  
  }

});
```